# How to shade only one circle out of 2 circles?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

In MS Word 2010, how to shade only one circle out of 2 overlapping circles?

I want it like this:

[image]

But I get this:

[image]

I need the overlap part to be white not yellow.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do it in Word. I'd do it in e.g. paint and just paste the final picture to Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not (easily/practically) possible to do this directly in Word. You ideally need the shape merge functions which are present in PowerPoint and Visio.

From https://www.shapechef.com/blog/how-to-merge-combine-shapes-in-powerpoint-2010

PowerPoint 2010 Configuration:

1. File menu and select Options
2. Customise ribbon
3. Choose 'Commands not in the ribbon' from the top left drop-down list.
4. Add the 'Combine Shapes' command to the ribbon.

In PowerPoint:

1. Create two overlapping ovals (right one above left).
2. Create 2 additional duplicates of these in the same place above.
3. Select both ovals from one of the duplicates.
4. Go to the [Combine Shapes](https://cdn.shapechef.com/blog/powerpoint-2010-combine-shapes-ribbon.png) command added previously and select Intersect.
   This will just leave the overlapping part.
5. Select the one set of the remaining overlapping ovals.
6. Combine Shapes: Subtract.
   This leaves the left oval with a chunk missing.
7. With the remaing ovals bring the left one to the top (Bring to Front command) and select both.
8. Combine Shapes: Subtract.
   This leaves the right oval with a chunk missing.
9. You can now fill any of those shapes and copy back to Word.
   [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvD86.png)

Comment: I am using MS office 2010, So It doesn't have **Fragment** option.

Comment: @RanguRamNaresh Updated for 2010 using subtract and intersect.